# JS validation troubles and some more gimmicks

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I've already have validated my form using php but I would like to change it to use javascript.For some reason it doesn't seem to work, and I cannot understand why.

```
<form name="adminFormNewMember" method="post" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>>
    <table id="tableNewUser">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="firstname" onblur="allLetter()" required autofocus></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
---------------------
<script>
    function allLetter()  
    {   
        var text = document.getElementById("firstname");
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
        if(text.value.match(letters))  
        {  
            return true;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            alert("message");  
            return false;  
        }  
    }
</script>
```

Obviously the form contains more stuff, I've omitted them for the sake of clarity.

Also I'd like to use the same function for more field such as lastname etc, but I don't know how to do that since I'm using the getElementById

Finally, I'd like to just highlight the textfield red for errors, green for correct etc.

**Clarification Edit** I still need the PHP part I just don't want it to validate. I need the validation to happen for each field onBlur, and then the data to be passed to the php function to be inserted in a DB etc.

Comment: your event needs to return false in the submit event of the form, not the blur event of the input

Comment: He probably wants the fields to validate when focus has left the field

Comment: Yes, exactly what Akshay said. The form is currently vaildated via the action that happens onSubmit. The action still needs to happens since data is check for html special chars, stripped, etc and then added to a DB

What I need is the validation to happen actively onBlur, and then onSubmit to pass the data to the PHP to add it to the DB etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <form name="adminFormNewMember" method="post" >
        <table id="tableNewUser">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="firstname" onblur="allLetter(this.id)" required autofocus></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        var allLetter = function(id){
          var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
          if(text.length ==0 || text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "").length != text.length) alert("Incorrect value")
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To use your function with several fields, just pass the id as a parameter (this.id), in allLetters function, pass the parameter to getElementById.

It seems your Regexp is not correct (or suffiscient), so first check the field is not empty then check if length of value equals lenngth of value with letters only. If so the field is correct, otherwise go for the alert.

Maybe you should consider using [jquery](https://jquery.com/) and the validate plugin [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/%20jquery%20validation%20plugin) witch can save you lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Returning true or false in your sample code is achieving nothing. What you need to do is, depending on whether validation is successful or not, add a CSS class to your input field. This CSS class should handle either background or border for your field to indicate that it did not match the criteria.

Instead of using onblur attribute, create an event listener for the blur event on your form fields. Delegate this listener to transfer control to a function which will take the value inside the event target and validate it. This should make your code more modular and apply to most fields.

Here is some code in basic javascript:

```
<table id="tableNewUser">
    <tr>
        <td>First Name </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstname" class="formFields"></td>
        <td>Last Name </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lastname" class="formFields"></td>
        <td>Fathers Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="fathername" class="formFields"></td>
    </tr>
```

```
<script>
    for(var i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("formFields").length ; i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("formFields")[i].addEventListener("blur", function(evt){
            var text = evt.target;
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
            if(text.value.match(letters))  
            {  
                evt.target.classList.remove('incorrectField');
                evt.target.classList.add('correctField');
            }  
            else  
            {  
                evt.target.classList.add('incorrectField');
                evt.target.classList.remove('correctField');
            }
        });
    }
```

```
<style>
    .incorrectField{
         background: red;
    }

    .correctField{
         background: green;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Wait, may I have a js script inside a .php file? Cause nothing seems to be working.

Comment: If you have HTML inside your PHP, you can have script too. What do you mean nothing is working?

Comment: @MrUber Why don't you use the updated code. I have verified that it works